# Error installing OpenLDAP in WSL2

Tags: debian, openldap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set up OpenLDAP to act as a non-secure proxy to Secure LDAP to support a legacy app so we can finish our migration to Azure Active Directory.  I'm trying to install OpenLDAP on my system with WSL2 (Pengwin) and am getting this error:

```sh
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up slapd (2.4.49+dfsg-4) ...
  Backing up /etc/ldap/slapd.d in /var/backups/slapd-... done.
  Moving old database directory to /var/backups:
  - directory unknown... done.
  Creating initial configuration... done.
  Creating LDAP directory... failed.
Loading the initial configuration from the ldif file () failed with
the following error while running slapadd:
    5ea1ae7a => mdb_next_id: get failed: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid (-30782)
    5ea1ae7a => mdb_tool_entry_put: cursor_open failed: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid (-30782)
    slapadd: could not add entry dn="dc=localdomain" (line=1): cursor_open failed: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid (-30782)
    5ea1ae7a mdb_tool_entry_close: database dc=localdomain: txn_commit failed: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid (-30782)
dpkg: error processing package slapd (--configure):
 installed slapd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I've already tried building OpenLDAP from source, but that fails because of missing dependencies in Berkeley DB.  Pengwin is a Debian-base distro and I cannot find the Berkeley DB 6 packages for new Debian distros.